# markup tags in PDF used by the printers, how to generate and QA the process

Tags: php, html, linux, printing, wkhtmltopdf

I need to enclose special markups for the printer in the PDF build process. 
I have the documentation from the printer company, which looks like:

```
<MailingName>Jon Doe</MailingName>
<MailingAddress1>123 Main St</MailingAddress1>
<MailingAddress2>Apartment 2</MailingAddress2>
<MailingCity>City</MailingCity>
<MailingState>CA</MailingState>
<MailingZip>94949</MailingZip>
```

We use wkhtmltopdf processor, and we included these tags in the content, but the printer said they are not prosent, and can't see it.

How to include these tags into the PDF? Is there some special way to do it?
Also do you know a QA tool that I can use to test these tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These tags are plain texts, and they should be placed clear in the text or encoded.